# error"Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "typeinfo for mbgl::RendererBackend"

Tags: xcode, mapbox

Error reporting when compiling code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbBVv.jpg)

Comment: error like this: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "typeinfo for mbgl::RendererBackend", referenced from:
      typeinfo for MARendererBackend in CustomMapKit(CustomMapKit-arm64-master.o)
  "mbgl::util::RunLoop::RunLoop(mbgl::util::RunLoop::Type)", referenced from:
      MGLInitializeRunLoop() in CustomMapKit(CustomMapKit-arm64-master.o)

Comment: There's not nearly enough context here to help you resolve your issue. Please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify whether this crash is happening at build time or runtime.